# Justifying text in \institute section

Tags: beamerposter

I am using a Beamer Poster Format. In order to justify the text, I am using `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and `\justifying`.

Beamer Poster Format has a `\institute {}` section immediately after the `\title` and `\author`. I am using this particular section to store the abstract and now I intend to justify the same text. But `\justifying` command is not working as `\institute {\justifying .... text ....}`.

The `\justifying` command is though working for the text within `\begin{document}` section.

Any opinions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), please!

Comment: I am not familiar with `beamerposter` and you didn't post a [MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<-Link), soi don't have anything to do a quick test. Try `\institute{\justifying Abstract here\par}` for a start.

Comment: \par has resolved the issue. Thanks Johannes,  CarLaTeX and Duck

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide a minimal working example, I've used an example found on Overleaf. If my answer doesn't solve your problem, please provide it.

For the alignment, you can use a `\parbox` within your `\institute`. I've used a width of `.5\linewidth` but, of course, you can choose anyone you like. Also only `\linewidth` to have the institute name cover all the line width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}

\title{Why don't people add a MWE?} 
\author{Paulinho van Duck} 
\institute{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{Duck fan club. Duck fan club was founded by Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda many years ago, and now it spreads all over the world. I have to add some more text to have an institute name with many lines, but I don't know what to write, so I'm writing some nonsense.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\justifying A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
A minimal working example is always necessary!
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]